# Angular MatTable - Understanding MatSort

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm not able to understand how MatSort works.
I have a MatTable with some columns. The first two columns are STATUS and ID. The Status is a number value (0,1 or 2) and the ID is a number.

I customize the HTML of the table in order to show a colored icon for the status (0=red, 1=yellow, 2=red).

It seems that the sort is not working properly. If I click three times the sort icon, the ID column sorts asc first, then desc and then it still remains on the desc sorting.

If I click three times on the STATUS column, it sorts asc first, then desc and then it returns at the first sorting status.

See the following gif:

[image]

I don't understand how it sorts the values. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview#changing-the-sort-order) states:

> By default, a sort header starts its sorting at asc and then desc.
>   Triggering the sort header after desc will remove sorting.

So what you see as behaviour with three clicks, seems to me correct.

Checkout [this example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/kdgqldqjadv)